# Watching MythTV on windows

Tags: windows, mythtv

I've got a [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) backend running happily on a headless linux server, and I can control it via [mythweb](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythWeb), including downloading and watching recorded programs in windows.

My next step is to watch live TV and recorded shows over the network.  Is there any software that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've got the [mythbox](http://code.google.com/p/mythbox/) script for [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) working happily for recorded shows, but with some slight audio stuttering for live TV, which disappears if I rewind a few seconds.

Edit: Getting a lot closer and happier using a pre-built [Windows frontend](http://members.iinet.net.au/~davco/).

Answer (score 4):

There's [WinMyth](http://winmyth.sourceforge.net/) and you can also try [MythTvPlayer](http://www.sudu.dk/mythtvplayer/index.php?page=home) but their both still quite experimental so YMMV

Comment: I currently use MythTvPlayer on my netbook.  It's simple but works great.

Comment: Looks neither of those have seen any activity for over a year.

Answer (score 1):

I just use XBMC with MythTV's UPnP support.  Works well enough for playback, but don't have as much control as a proper Myth Frontend; and doesn't do commercial skipping.